# Angularjs $scope is not updating

Tags: angularjs

In my application, from one controller i am updating $scope.needs.Then when i click a button, it is going to another controller. There i am getting the updated value of $scope.needs. But when click on back button, it is going to the previous controller. There i am not getting the updated value of $scope.needs. How to solve this issue.

This is the first controller.

```js
function CommitmentCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $http, UIData, cust, productList) {
  $scope.needs = $scope.customer.priorities.list;
}
```

In this controller

```js
$scope.increment = function(index) {
    $scope.needs[index].commitment = parseFloat   ($('#custom_commitment_'+index).val()) + 1000;

    }
```

Here $scope.needs updated..rite? Then when click on button,the below function is called

```js
$scope.gotoSummary = function(){
  $scope.customer.priorities.list = $scope.needs;
}
```

Here $scope.customer.priorities.list contains the updated value.

This is the next controller

```js
function SummaryCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $http, UIData, cust) {
  $scope.$parent.needs = $scope.customer.priorities.list;
}
```

Then click on back button invokes the first controller,but there in $scope,updated value is not there.

**How do I update $scope.needs in both places?**

Comment: could you please share fiddle

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to acheive this
1)Using $rootScope
2)Using Angular Service

1)Using $rootScope

```
<html ng-app="jsf">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="CategoriesCtrl">
        <input type="button" value="update" ng-click="update()" />
    </div>
      <div ng-controller="secondCtrl">
        <input type="button" value="check" ng-click="check()" />
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('jsf', []);


        app.controller('CategoriesCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
            $rootScope.block = [3, 2, 1, 0];
            $scope.update = function () {
                alert("123");
                $rootScope.block[1] = '5';
            }
        });

        app.controller('secondCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
            $scope.check = function () {
                alert($rootScope.block[1]);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

2)You have to create a angular service and maintain the value inside service and share the value across controllers

Comment: service should be suggestion #1. `$rootScope` shouldn't be used to store data